# My third party Realtek 8153 USB Ethernet adaptor does not work with macOS Big Sur 11.6.1

Tags: usb, big-sur, ethernet

My 2014 MacBook Air is running macOS Big Sur 11.6.1. I am trying to use a [Lention CB-H23s-0.5M USB A hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VPFH9VD). The USB portion of the hub works; the Ethernet adaptor does not.

I tested the Lention hub with my Ubuntu 18 Linux machine and everything worked, proving that the hardware is fully functional.

In **::apple:: > System Report > USB 3.0 Bus > USB2.0 Hub > USB 10/100/1000 LAN**, I see that the Ethernet adaptor chip is a Realtek 8153.

How do I get the Ethernet adaptor to work with my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Merely updating to macOS Big Sur 11.6.2 fixes the problem. No further effort is required.